# Determine and classify stationary points of the function $f (x) = x(1− \ln x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm stuck on what to do after finding the derivative.

So far I have done:

$$f(x)=x(1-\ln x)$$

$$f'(x)=1(1-\ln x)\frac1x\tag{Applying the chain rule}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac1x(1-\ln x)$$
(as the original question differentiated)

From there where do i proceed and determine and classify all the stationary points?

Comment: Odd to apply the chain rule when the outermost operation is multiplication.

Comment: So I expand the brackets to make the process simpler rather than differentiating first

Comment: you want the product rule here, not the chain rule

Comment: Yes I've seen it now, that makes it a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

Stationary points are defined as points where the derivative is zero, so solving for solutions of $f'(x)=0$ but first note:
$$f(x)=x(1-\ln x)$$
$$f'(x)=\color{red}{1}\color{green}{(1-\ln x)}+\color{red}{x}\color{green}{(-1/x)}\\=1-\ln x-1\\=-\ln x\tag{product rule}$$
now, you want to solve the equation:
$$\ln(x)=0$$

Comment: It's possible to factorise ln(x)?

Comment: @AMN uh what. Just take $e$ to the power of both sides

Comment: @TheBestMagician got the answer lol my brain had a dumb moment thank you anyways

Comment: @AMN no problem, happens to the best of us ;)